# PostgreSQL bulk update

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE atc_codes (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying,
    atc_code character varying
);

INSERT INTO atc_codes (id, name, atc_code) VALUES (1, 'granisetron', 'A04AA02');

INSERT INTO atc_codes (id, name, atc_code) VALUES (2, '', 'A04AA02');

INSERT INTO atc_codes (id, name, atc_code) VALUES (3, '', 'A04AA02');

INSERT INTO atc_codes (id, name, atc_code) VALUES (4, 'metoclopramide', 'A03FA01');

INSERT INTO atc_codes (id, name, atc_code) VALUES (5, '', 'A03FA01');

INSERT INTO atc_codes (id, name, atc_code) VALUES (6, '', 'A03FA01');
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM atc_codes;
```

| id | name | atc_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | granisetron | A04AA02 |
| 2 |  | A04AA02 |
| 3 |  | A04AA02 |
| 4 | metoclopramide | A03FA01 |
| 5 |  | A03FA01 |
| 6 |  | A03FA01 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Z47Kswa19G6arMGTuBoCj/0)

Now I want to do the following things:

1. Update all records with `act_code` equal to `A04AA02` to have `granisetron` value in the `name` column.
2. Update all records with `act_code` equal to `A03FA01` to have `metoclopramide` value in the `name` column.

In the real database there will be much more scenarios like that so using something like CASE statement is impossible in that case.

Can I do that in one query instead of two?

Comment: How do you get your "scenarios" ? Do you have a file listing them or something like that ?

Comment: No, this is just big legacy databases that have the same problem for many atc codes.

Comment: If you can't use a CASE expression, then you will have to write one UPDATE statement for each condition.

Comment: I don't understand: you know you must update rows, but how ? There must be a mapping somewhere. For example, if you have a CSV file, there will be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with using view:

```
WITH act_codes_name AS (
  SELECT 
    name, 
    atc_code 
  FROM 
    atc_codes 
  WHERE 
    name IS NOT NULL
)

UPDATE 
  atc_codes
SET 
  name = act_codes_name.name
FROM act_codes_name
WHERE act_codes_name.atc_code = atc_codes.atc_code;
```

Comment: Your question was misleading as it did not mention that you wanted to update rows with missing names from rows with filled names.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you could use a `CASE WHEN` (standard **SQL** *"switch case"*) in the `SET` clause:

```sql
UPDATE atc_codes
SET name = CASE
        WHEN atc_code = 'A04AA02' THEN 'granisetron'
        WHEN atc_code = 'A03FA01' THEN 'metoclopramide'
        ELSE name
    END
WHERE atc_code IN('A04AA02', 'A03FA01');
```

To avoid mistakes, I added a `ELSE` (equivalent to a *default case*) and a `WHERE` clause to prevent updating rows that don't match. Both do the same thing and I think you could just use one or the other.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately, this solution will not gonna work because there are more cases like that and I will not be able to handle them all with the CASE statement.

Comment: @MateuszUrbański okay could you please update your question so I can understand why my answer won't work ? I'd be glad to update it if I can find something that fits your needs.